# Java - Split an array of arrays into multiple arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hello fellow programmers, I am having trouble with this logic, what I want to do is split an array of arrays into multiple arrays in an Android Studio application (java).

I have an array like this:

```
int[][] goal = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {0, 7, 8} };
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
int[] zero = {1,2,3};
int[] one = {4,5,6};
int[] two = {0,7,8};
```

But I am having trouble cause i though i could set the array like this

```
int[] zero = goal [1][];
int[] one = goal [2][];
int[] two = goal [3][];
```

And I cant, so i am getting here to know if any of you guys could me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: `int[] zero = goal[0], one = goal[1], two = goal[2];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your logic...

**Change** this:

```
int[] zero = goal [1][];
int[] one = goal [2][];
int[] two = goal [3][];
```

**to** this:

```
int[] zero = goal [0];
int[] one = goal [1];
int[] two = goal [2];
```

Answer (score 3):

You should write-

```
int[] zero = goal[0];
int[] one = goal[1];
int[] two = goal[2];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking is correct, but your implementation is wrong. Try:

```
int[] zero = goal[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get any value of individual arrays and goal can be of any dimension.

```
int[][] goal =  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {0, 7, 8} };

        for(int i=0; i<goal.length; i++){
            int [] actualArray = goal[i];
            for(int j =0; j< actualArray.length; j++){
                // you can get each value of individual array with the following code: actualArray[j];
            }
        }
```